# Styling for "this" inside "forEach" function

Tags: javascript, html, styling

I'm trying to build a small tool for my self to use in my upcoming projects, but I'm having a small issue.

while I'm adding a styling inside forEach Function for some reason it's not succeeding!

so here' how's my code looks like:

```
<p data-att1="30">1</p>
<p data-att1="30">2</p>
<p data-att3="30">3</p>
<p data-att3="30">4</p>



let dataAttr = "[data-att1], [data-att2], [data-att3]";
let dataMain = document.querySelectorAll(dataAttr);
let p = "px";

const mainFn = () => {
  dataMain.forEach(function () {
    this.style.marginBottom = document.querySelector('[data-att1]').getAttribute('data-att1') + p;
    this.style.marginTop = document.querySelector('[data-att3]').getAttribute('data-att3') + p;
  });
};
```

Comment: Done, Added the html

Answer (score 0):

You are not working in the correct `this` scope. Instead use `el` as element parameter and refer to that scope.

```
let dataAttr = "[data-att1], [data-att2], [data-att3]";
let dataMain = document.querySelectorAll(dataAttr);
let p = "px";

const mainFn = () => {
  dataMain.forEach(function (el) {
    el.style.marginBottom = document.querySelector('[data-att1]').getAttribute('data-att1') + p;
    el.style.marginTop = document.querySelector('[data-att3]').getAttribute('data-att3') + p;
  });
};
```

Comment: tried it before it's only giving the first styling property (margin-bottom) for all selected elements.

Comment: kindly change the data-att2 to > data-att1 (typing mistake)

Comment: @K_LUN What exactly do you want to achive? It looks you want something different than the questions asks.

Comment: this but in pure javascript : https://github.com/Khaledmnmnh/Useful-CSS-Library/blob/master/Spacing/spacing.js